# Match multiple tags to a column based on words (partial match or complete) in the column element

Tags: python, pandas, matching, data-manipulation, string-matching

i have two data sets such as:

```
  Tags
Insurance
Asset
Bank
Municipality
Government
Corporate
Gas
General US Public Finance
Real Estate
```

and so on...
I want to assign these tags to other dataset.

the second dataset is like this:

```
     UserTags
Real Estate Insurance
Corporate - Finance Company
Corporate - Energy / Utility / Commodities
Corporate - Non-Financial Other
Government Entity - Central Bank
Government Entity - Regulator
Government Entity - Municipality
Asset Bank
```

I want to use Python to match these two dataset like this:

> ```
>      UserTags                                        AssignedTags
> Real Estate Insurance                                 Real Estate
> Real Estate Insurance                                 Insurance
> Corporate - Finance Company                           Corporate
> Corporate - Energy / Utility / Commodities            Corporate
> Corporate - Non-Financial Other                       Corporate
> Government Entity - Central Bank                      Government
> Government Entity - Central Bank                      Bank
> Government Entity - Regulator                         Government
> Government Entity - Municipality                      Government
> Government Entity - Municipality                      Municipality
> Asset Bank                                            Asset
> Asset Bank                                            Bank
> ```

So basically, first tag *"Real Estate Insurance"* contained both tags: Real Estate and Insurance so its coming twice, containing one tag of each. Same is for *"Government Entity - Municipality"*.

How can I do this? Also, if there is not a full, match, can I assign a partial match of tag? for example:

```
  Tag        AssignedTag

Municipal   Municipality
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both of these are pandas Series. I'm referring to the first Series in the question as "tags" and the second one as "user_tags."

```
matched = tags.apply(
    lambda x: user_tags.loc[tags.str.contains(x)]
)
final_table = pd.concat([tags,matched],axis=1)
```